# Set featured image from external URL

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have been searching high and low for a work-around to set a featured image from an external URL. I understand by default the image must be on my server to get re-sized and displayed.

Essentially I have a dozen live web cams that take pictures every 30 minutes, and I need to be able to set up a *wall* of good sized thumbs like [this](http://spadeinvaders.com/themes/elastico/) so all images can be scanned on one page.

Please let me know if you can provide a quick snippet that can help.

Comment: why do they have to be featured images? especially since they are updated regularly, it makes much more sense to me to write something to handle this outside the media library.

Comment: Please forgive me, I'm not quite sure I follow...Can you elaborate on your thoughts?

Comment: I think Milo is saying you can just place the image in your content, creating a function or custom field for keep as metadata.

Comment: I've developed a plugin to do this so I thought I'd share. You can read more about it here http://epicplugins.com/external-url-link-to-featured-images/